# Apache and Tomcat Server Cross Domain

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat, cross-domain

I have **three distinct** heavily coded web-projects; two of them (*new*) is newly developed with **Java/Script**, the other (*old*) one with **PHP**. All of these three project has some common resources like HTML containers, Element classes etc. Moreover, one of the Java project is Main Project that call the other two projects.

The issue is that Java projects run on a **Tomcat Server**, PHP needs to run on **Apache Server**. And PHP project has some location paths for resources like *"../SomeResourceFolder/somePage.php"*. However, when I run Main Project (**Java**) on Tomcat Server which has **"localhost:8080"** I could not reach **PHP** project which is run on Apache Server with **"localhost:80"**, even if I accomplish to reach PHP project, PHP one fails to reach common resources in Tomcat.

I solve the issue a little bit unconvincing way with JavaBridge and Quercus; they help to run PHP on Tomcat Server. However, again I have some path problems.

Actually these projects runs on production with load-balancer which direct request to related server. I try to simulate this or at least run PHP on Apache, Java on Tomcat and connect them somehow. How can I construct this kind of structure without cross domain problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue by using "Tomcat Connector". It connect Apache and Tomcat by defining Tomcat as worker, and send HTTP request with given path configuration.

You can follow [guide](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/ApachePlusTomcat_HowTo.html) given by Nanyang University. In guide Tomcat 6 and Apache 2.2 are used but I used Tomcat 7 and Apache 2.4 with the same directions.